# Insert array into a single field in a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a `SELECT` drown down list, I would like to have it loaded in 1 of 2 ways.

First way is pulling data from database with ID, name, and Value - This way will be loaded from other pages.

Second way, I would like to load from a Single line in the database with Name and Value. But I want to have that value be loaded with an array.

How do I load that array into the database?

```
$name = 'name';
$value = array( 'red' => 'Red', 'blue' => 'Blue' );
$SQL = 'INSERT INTO table_name (name, value) VALUES ($name,$value);
```

I expect when I run the `SELECT * from table_name WHERE name = "name"` to use that array in the value field right away.

---

With what "RakeshJakhar" said, to use the implode and explode onto `$value`

```
$value = array( 'red' => 'Red', 'blue' => 'Blue' );

print_r( $value );
echo "<br />";
echo implode( ",", $value );
echo "<br />";
$implode = implode( ",", $value );
$explode = explode( ',', $implode );
print_r( $explode );
```

Results:

```
Array ( [red] => Red [blue] => Blue ) 

Red,Blue

Array ( [0] => Red [1] => Blue )
```

Comment: I will be using Question Marks for the Value fields, I am just writing quick hand for example.

Comment: You can use implode with a separator like ; and when retrieving use explode in array

Comment: Json might be a good choice of encoding

Comment: Just use multiple columns. There's no advantage to do otherwise.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar - I can see how to do the implode and Explode, but on Explode, How do I create the key's in the array on explode?

Comment: @user8776656 do you need key like red,blue ?

Comment: use json_encode and json_decode

Comment: Yes, the keys will go into value and other will be in shown.

Comment: I have answered with an example, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json_encode` and `json_decode`

```
$value  = array( 'red' => 'Red', 'blue' => 'Blue' );
$column = json_encode($value);
```

So the inserted value `{"red":"Red","blue":"Blue"}`

When you are fetching value use `json_decode`

```
$values = json_decode($column,true);
```